# Why Object.create doesn't clone properties as expected?

Tags: javascript, object

If I type this into console:

```
var x = {a: 1};
var y = Object.create(x);
console.log(y);
```

It shows `{}`. But if I run it in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bortao/ubth6wsa/) it shows `{a: 1}`, which is the expected result. Also here:

```js
var x = {a: 1};
var y = Object.create(x);
console.log(y);
```

So what is going on?

Comment: Your snippet above shows `{ "a": 1 }`.. for me.

Comment: Because `Object.create` doesn't *clone* anything. It creates a new (empty) object that *inherits*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Runs as expected even in console. You just have to extend the Object.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Answer

> Why doesn't Object.create clone properties as expected?

Because `Object.create` isn't supposed to clone properties.

### JavaScript objects are tricky

If we look at the documentation of [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), it says:

> The Object.create() method creates a new object, using an existing object ***as the prototype*** of the newly created object.

Besides its own properties, each object in JavaScript also inherits properties from its prototype.

Now, the tricky part is – inherited properties are only visible in some cases. For example:

- Property accessor – `y.a` or `y['a']` – ✅ sees inherited properties

  - `console.log(y.a); // outputs 1`
- `Object.keys`, `Object.values`, `Object.entries` – ❌ doesn't see inherited properties

  - `console.log(Object.keys(y)); // outputs []`

These concepts are much more comprehensively covered in [Enumerability and ownership of properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties).

For a more thorough explanation of prototypes, see [Object prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes).

### Why does JSFiddle print it differently than Chrome?

Apparently, JSFiddle's implementation of `console` enumerates inherited properties, whereas Chrome's `console` implementation doesn't.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this thrice - once for each part of the explanation :-)